# get a reference to a list inside another class

Tags: android

In my app I have a list of Trucks that are displayed in a lisview, and every Truck has a list of cases inside it. My question is how do I get a reference to that list of cases inside the truck from the main activity.

```
public class Truck  {

private String name;
public List<Roadcase> cases;


public Truck() {
cases = new ArrayList<Roadcase>();
}

public Truck(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.cases = new ArrayList<Roadcase>();
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void addRoadcase(Roadcase roadcases) {
    cases.add(roadcases);       
}

public void deleteRoadcase(Roadcase roadcases){
    cases.remove(roadcases);        
}
public int numberOfRoadcases(){
    return cases.size();
}   

public List<Roadcase> getList() {
    return cases;
}
}
```

my Truck class.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the method `getList` from your activity (

```
public List<Roadcase> getList() {
    return cases;
}
```

)

For example:

```
Truck truck = new Truck();
List<Roadcase> list = truck.getList();
```

Comment: So then my other question is how do I format it into a Custom Adapter that I made? this.roadcaseAdapter = new RoadcaseAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Truck.getCases()); ?

Comment: assumin `truck` (with a lower case t) is your instance of `Truck`, then - `new RoadcaseAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, truck.getCases());`